# Как обрабатывать multipart/form-data на NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, html5

Обычная форма на клиенте:

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <button type="submit" name="button">Отправить файл</button>
</form>
```

Как правильно обработать файл без использования express/koa на сервере и без AJAX на клиенте? Главное, что не могу понять, - как получить имя файла. Сами данные файла пайпятся нормально - файл успешно сохраняется на сервере. 
Используя AJAX все отсылается без проблем - и сам файл, и его название (мы ведь сами и задаем), но интересует как это сделать именно средствами только HTML5 на клиенте (как я понял, multipart/form-data специально для этого и создан) и обработкой на ноде.

```js
switch (req.method) {
  case 'POST':
    // вместо filename сейчас заглушка из рандомного названия
    receiveFile(__dirname + '/files/' + 'filename', req, res);
  break;
  
  /*
  ....
  */
}

function receiveFile(filePath, req, res) {
  let file = fs.createWriteStream(filePath, {flags: 'wx'});
  req.pipe(file);
  /*
  ....
  */
}
```

Comment: Вы можете использовать какую-то библиотеку, например, [multiparty](https://github.com/pillarjs/multiparty)

Answer (score 1):

Да хоть с экспрессом, хоть без экспресса - всё равно так закодированную форму надо разбирать на поля и файлы. Для этого берём модульчик `formidable` - и разбираем:

```
http.Server(function(req, res) {

    if(req.url == '/upfile') {
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
            if(err) console.error(err);
            console.log(fields);
            console.log(files);
            res.end('thank-you');
        });
    } else {
        file.serve(req, res);
    }

}).listen(3000, function() {console.log('PORT: 3000')});
```

Первый консоль напишет поля (готовый объект, естественно), а второй напишет данные о посланных файлах, в том числе - путь, по которому он файл сохранил и какое случайное имя (без расширения оно) ему присвоено - дальше делайте с ним, мол, чё хочите.

(Но есть проблема. Такую форму не принимает проверка на межсайтовые запросы - токен-то не видит до её разбора. Как её преодолеть, я чёта пока не знаю.)

Comment: Что это за проверка такая, на "межсайтовые запросы"? :)